# Passing a value from one part of the MongoDB aggregation to another to sort the results

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation

I got some problems with a MongoDB aggregation I'm trying to build. I would like to get a table with statistics of how much do I play some games during a week. I need to get it into the table sorted by games in rows and days of the week in columns. Cells will contain a percentage of how much each game was played in a day (meaning 100% is a total of all the games played in a concrete day). I would like to have the rows sorted by total times a certain game was played in a week (the weeks most played the game on the top).  This is how I want it to look at the end:

[final table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTd2u.png)

I got a great advice from dickless on how to count percentage: [MongoDB aggregation - how to get a percentage value of how many times an event occurred per day of week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47332116/mongodb-aggregation-how-to-get-a-percentage-value-of-how-many-times-an-event-o)

My current aggregation looks like this:

```
    db.games.aggregate([
    { $project: { 
        "_id": 0, 
        "date" : { $dayOfWeek: "$date" }, 
        "title": "$title"

    } },

    { $group: { 
        "_id": { "title": "$title", "date": "$date" }, 
        "total": { $sum: 1 } 

    } }, 

    { $group: { 
        "_id": "$_id.date", 
        "types": { $push: { "title": "$_id.title", total: "$total" } }, 
        "grandTotal": { $sum: "$total" } 

    } }, 

    { $unwind: "$types"}, 

    { $project: { 
        "_id": 0,
        "title": "$types.title", 
        "percentage": { $divide: [ "$types.total", "$grandTotal" ] }, 
        "day": { $arrayElemAt: [ [ "0", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" ], "$_id" ] } 

    } }, 

    { $group: {
        "_id": "$title", 
        "days": {$push: {"day":"$day", "percentage": "$percentage"} } 

    } } 
])
```

This is the JSON im getting from it:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "Bomberman",
    "days" : [
        {
            "day" : "Tue",
            "percentage" : 0.2
        },
        {
            "day" : "Thu",
            "percentage" : 0.14285714285714285
        },
        {
            "day" : "Wed",
            "percentage" : 0.09090909090909091
        },
        {
            "day" : "Fri",
            "percentage" : 0.08333333333333333
        }
    ]
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "GTA",
    "days" : [
        {
            "day" : "Tue",
            "percentage" : 0.4
        },
        {
            "day" : "Mon",
            "percentage" : 0.375
        },
        {
            "day" : "Thu",
            "percentage" : 0.2857142857142857
        },
        {
            "day" : "Wed",
            "percentage" : 0.2727272727272727
        },
        {
            "day" : "Fri",
            "percentage" : 0.3333333333333333
        }
    ]
},

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "Forza",
    "days" : [
        {
            "day" : "Tue",
            "percentage" : 0.1
        },
        {
            "day" : "Mon",
            "percentage" : 0.25
        },
        {
            "day" : "Thu",
            "percentage" : 0.14285714285714285
        },
        {
            "day" : "Wed",
            "percentage" : 0.18181818181818182
        },
        {
            "day" : "Fri",
            "percentage" : 0.25
        }
    ]
},

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : "Pacman",
    "days" : [
        {
            "day" : "Tue",
            "percentage" : 0.1
        },
        {
            "day" : "Mon",
            "percentage" : 0.125
        },
        {
            "day" : "Thu",
            "percentage" : 0.14285714285714285
        },
        {
            "day" : "Wed",
            "percentage" : 0.18181818181818182
        },
        {
            "day" : "Fri",
            "percentage" : 0.08333333333333333
        }
    ]
},

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : "BattleField",
    "days" : [
        {
            "day" : "Tue",
            "percentage" : 0.2
        },
        {
            "day" : "Mon",
            "percentage" : 0.25
        },
        {
            "day" : "Thu",
            "percentage" : 0.2857142857142857
        },
        {
            "day" : "Wed",
            "percentage" : 0.2727272727272727
        },
        {
            "day" : "Fri",
            "percentage" : 0.25
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the JSON that im trying to get (sorted from the most played game in total, to the least played game):

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "GTA",
    "days" : [
        {
            "day" : "Mon",
            "percentage" : 0.375
        },
        {
            "day" : "Tue",
            "percentage" : 0.4
        },
        {
            "day" : "Wed",
            "percentage" : 0.2727272727272727
        },
        {
            "day" : "Thu",
            "percentage" : 0.2857142857142857
        },
        {
            "day" : "Fri",
            "percentage" : 0.3333333333333333
        }
    ]
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "BattleField",
    "days" : [
        {
            "day" : "Mon",
            "percentage" : 0.25
        },
        {
            "day" : "Tue",
            "percentage" : 0.2
        },
        {
            "day" : "Wed",
            "percentage" : 0.2727272727272727
        },
        {
            "day" : "Thu",
            "percentage" : 0.2857142857142857
        },
        {
            "day" : "Fri",
            "percentage" : 0.25
        }
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "Forza",
    "days" : [
        {
            "day" : "Mon",
            "percentage" : 0.25
        },
        {
            "day" : "Tue",
            "percentage" : 0.1
        },
        {
            "day" : "Wed",
            "percentage" : 0.18181818181818182
        },
        {
            "day" : "Thu",
            "percentage" : 0.14285714285714285
        },
        {
            "day" : "Fri",
            "percentage" : 0.25
        }
    ]
},

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : "Pacman",
    "days" : [
        {
            "day" : "Mon",
            "percentage" : 0.125
        },
        {
            "day" : "Tue",
            "percentage" : 0.1
        },
        {
            "day" : "Wed",
            "percentage" : 0.18181818181818182
        },
        {
            "day" : "Thu",
            "percentage" : 0.14285714285714285
        },
        {
            "day" : "Fri",
            "percentage" : 0.08333333333333333
        }
    ]
},

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : "Bomberman",
    "days" : [
        {
            "day" : "Tue",
            "percentage" : 0.2
        },
        {
            "day" : "Wed",
            "percentage" : 0.09090909090909091
        },
        {
            "day" : "Thu",
            "percentage" : 0.14285714285714285
        },
        {
            "day" : "Fri",
            "percentage" : 0.08333333333333333
        }
    ]
},
```

The data im feeding to the DB:

```
[
{"title":"GTA","date":"2017-11-13"},
{"title":"GTA","date":"2017-11-13"},
{"title":"GTA","date":"2017-11-13"},
{"title":"Pacman","date":"2017-11-13"},
{"title":"BattleField","date":"2017-11-13"},
{"title":"BattleField","date":"2017-11-13"},
{"title":"Forza","date":"2017-11-13"},
{"title":"Forza","date":"2017-11-13"},
{"title":"GTA","date":"2017-11-14"},
{"title":"GTA","date":"2017-11-14"},
{"title":"GTA","date":"2017-11-14"},
{"title":"GTA","date":"2017-11-14"},
{"title":"BattleField","date":"2017-11-14"},
{"title":"BattleField","date":"2017-11-14"},
{"title":"Forza","date":"2017-11-14"},
{"title":"Pacman","date":"2017-11-14"},
{"title":"Bomberman","date":"2017-11-14"},
{"title":"Bomberman","date":"2017-11-14"},
{"title":"GTA","date":"2017-11-15"},
{"title":"GTA","date":"2017-11-15"},
{"title":"GTA","date":"2017-11-15"},
{"title":"BattleField","date":"2017-11-15"},
{"title":"BattleField","date":"2017-11-15"},
{"title":"BattleField","date":"2017-11-15"},
{"title":"Forza","date":"2017-11-15"},
{"title":"Forza","date":"2017-11-15"},
{"title":"Pacman","date":"2017-11-15"},
{"title":"Pacman","date":"2017-11-15"},
{"title":"Bomberman","date":"2017-11-15"},
{"title":"GTA","date":"2017-11-16"},
{"title":"GTA","date":"2017-11-16"},
{"title":"BattleField","date":"2017-11-16"},
{"title":"BattleField","date":"2017-11-16"},
{"title":"Forza","date":"2017-11-16"},
{"title":"Bomberman","date":"2017-11-16"},
{"title":"Pacman","date":"2017-11-16"},
{"title":"GTA","date":"2017-11-17"},
{"title":"GTA","date":"2017-11-17"},
{"title":"GTA","date":"2017-11-17"},
{"title":"GTA","date":"2017-11-17"},
{"title":"BattleField","date":"2017-11-17"},
{"title":"BattleField","date":"2017-11-17"},
{"title":"BattleField","date":"2017-11-17"},
{"title":"Forza","date":"2017-11-17"},
{"title":"Forza","date":"2017-11-17"},
{"title":"Forza","date":"2017-11-17"},
{"title":"Bomberman","date":"2017-11-17"},
{"title":"Pacman","date":"2017-11-17"}
]
```

Now my question is how can I sort the rows by the weekly most played game? I think I would need to create some sub-aggregation or subpipeline, where will I count the total number of plays per game and then pass this result to the end of my aggregation to sort, but I couldn't find the way to do this.

I'm really a MongoDB noob so I will appreciate any advice on this, thanks!

Comment: what is out put u expected ?add it json into Question

Comment: thanks for the advice, ive added the expected JSON under the one im currently getting

Comment: Expose `"$types.total"` in the last projection, sum it in the following group, and add a sorting stage afterwards.

Comment: Great, it works! thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alex Blex for pointing me the right way, this is the solution to above question:

```
db.games.aggregate([
    { $project: { 
        "_id": 0, 
        "date" : { $dayOfWeek: "$date" }, 
        "title": "$title"

    } },

    { $group: { 
        "_id": { "title": "$title", "date": "$date" }, 
        "total": { $sum: 1 } 

    } }, 

    { $group: { 
        "_id": "$_id.date", 
        "types": { $push: { "title": "$_id.title", total: "$total" } }, 
        "grandTotal": { $sum: "$total" } 

    } }, 

    { $sort: {
        "_id": 1 

    } }, // This sorts the arrays with days from Monday to Sunday 

    { $unwind: "$types"}, 

    { $project: { 
        "_id": 0,
        "title": "$types.title", 
        "percentage": { $divide: [ "$types.total", "$grandTotal" ] }, 
        "day": { $arrayElemAt: [ [ "0", "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" ], "$_id" ] }, 
        "supertotal" : "$types.total" // This exposes the total numbers of times a game was played per particular dayOfWeek
    } }, 

    { $group: {
        "_id": "$title", 
        "days": {$push: {"day":"$day", "percentage": "$percentage"} }, 
        "supertotal" : {$sum: "$supertotal"} // This sums the total numbers of times a game was played in a week

    } }, 

    { $sort: {
        "supertotal": -1
    } } // This sorts the documents from the most played game
])
```

Final JSON:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "GTA",
    "days" : [
        {
            "day" : "Mon",
            "percentage" : 0.375
        },
        {
            "day" : "Tue",
            "percentage" : 0.4
        },
        {
            "day" : "Wed",
            "percentage" : 0.2727272727272727
        },
        {
            "day" : "Thu",
            "percentage" : 0.2857142857142857
        },
        {
            "day" : "Fri",
            "percentage" : 0.3333333333333333
        }
    ],
    "supertotal" : 16.0
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "BattleField",
    "days" : [
        {
            "day" : "Mon",
            "percentage" : 0.25
        },
        {
            "day" : "Tue",
            "percentage" : 0.2
        },
        {
            "day" : "Wed",
            "percentage" : 0.2727272727272727
        },
        {
            "day" : "Thu",
            "percentage" : 0.2857142857142857
        },
        {
            "day" : "Fri",
            "percentage" : 0.25
        }
    ],
    "supertotal" : 12.0
},

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "Forza",
    "days" : [
        {
            "day" : "Mon",
            "percentage" : 0.25
        },
        {
            "day" : "Tue",
            "percentage" : 0.1
        },
        {
            "day" : "Wed",
            "percentage" : 0.18181818181818182
        },
        {
            "day" : "Thu",
            "percentage" : 0.14285714285714285
        },
        {
            "day" : "Fri",
            "percentage" : 0.25
        }
    ],
    "supertotal" : 9.0
},

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : "Pacman",
    "days" : [
        {
            "day" : "Mon",
            "percentage" : 0.125
        },
        {
            "day" : "Tue",
            "percentage" : 0.1
        },
        {
            "day" : "Wed",
            "percentage" : 0.18181818181818182
        },
        {
            "day" : "Thu",
            "percentage" : 0.14285714285714285
        },
        {
            "day" : "Fri",
            "percentage" : 0.08333333333333333
        }
    ],
    "supertotal" : 6.0
},

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : "Bomberman",
    "days" : [
        {
            "day" : "Tue",
            "percentage" : 0.2
        },
        {
            "day" : "Wed",
            "percentage" : 0.09090909090909091
        },
        {
            "day" : "Thu",
            "percentage" : 0.14285714285714285
        },
        {
            "day" : "Fri",
            "percentage" : 0.08333333333333333
        }
    ],
    "supertotal" : 5.0
}
```